# Refresh the table after every operation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting data from the rest service in a table using `ng-repeat` in AngularJS. I want to refresh the table after every operation. I am able to do the page refresh using `location.reload()` function. But I want to refresh my table only.

Comment: why you want to refresh your table ?if you are in angularjs and you must be getting your latest data in some $scope,in angular will automatically get updated.

Comment: Just call that function on every operation this will solve yours problem

Comment: Add your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo http://dojo.telerik.com/OwUHe

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [{name:'abc',id:1},{name:'xyz',id:2}];

  //adding here
  $scope.add = function(dataObj){
          $scope.data.push(dataObj);
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

location.reload is not good way for refreshing a table. for this you should call function for reloading a table after every operation. you can specify a function in controller for table reloading.